# AWS Elasticsearch Rollover Index with dates in the index name

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to have index with date in the index name that automatically rolls over everyday.
As for testing, I have ISM policy that rolls over everyhour

```
{
    "policy_id": "test",
    "description": "hot to warm every hour.",
    "default_state": "hot",
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "hot",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "min_index_age": "1h"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "transitions": [
                {
                    "state_name": "warm",
                    "conditions": {
                        "min_index_age": "2h"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "warm",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "retry": {
                        "count": 5,
                        "backoff": "exponential",
                        "delay": "1m"
                    },
                    "warm_migration": {}
                }
            ],
            "transitions": []
        }
    ],
    "ism_template": [
        {
            "index_patterns": [
                "test-*"
            ],
            "priority": 100,
            "last_updated_time": 1640874381088
        }
    ]
}
```

And Index Template with rollover alias

```
PUT /_template/test_template
{ 
  "index_patterns" : ["test-*"],
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "opendistro.index_state_management.rollover_alias": "test_alias",
      "refresh_interval" : "1s",
      "number_of_shards" : "1",
      "number_of_replicas" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I created initial rollover index

```
# PUT <test-{now/h{YYYYMMddHH}}>
PUT %3Ckbtest-ai-detector-%7Bnow%2Fh%7BYYYYMMdd%7D%7D%3E
{
  "aliases": {
    "test_alias": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

which created `test-2021123016`.
But whenever ISM tries to roll over, I get following error

```
{
    "cause": "For input string: \"{now/h{YYYYMMddHH}}\"",
    "message": "Failed to rollover index [index=test-2021123016]"
}
```

Is it not able to use [date math expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html) when it comes to ISM policy?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ISM for this case, just construct index name in your app when indexing (using current time like `test-2021-12-30`; use index template to control settings and mappings) and use wildcard index for searching (`test-*`?).

Comment: Hi @ilvar, thank you for the response. I guess I can call create index and rollover api manually. But since ISM supports both operations, I was wondering if I could utilize it.

Comment: ISM is more useful for rolling over based on index size or size+age (when indexing rate can vary a lot). If you just need daily or weekly or monthly indices it's easier to implement without ISM. You don't *have* to use a feature just because it is there.

Comment: @ilvar how about a managed solution when the ISM is used also to transition the indexes between states - hot/warm/cold? I'd like to have a date in the index name along with the rolling option based on age so when you want to have a specific index transitioned back from cold to warm when you pick it by date and no need to query using API its creation date. Same case when running manual snapshots and restoring specific indexes from that snapshot.

Comment: @rivar_ sorry for the delay. Yes, I think you can use ISM when indices are created by your app (with a date) - just provide the policy in index settings as usual. That said, I don't think you can move index "backwards" from warm to hot - I mean, you can, but the ISM will move it back shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only date to add in your rolled over index then you can use below format.

```
PUT /%3Ckbtest-ai-detector-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D-000001%3E
{
  "aliases": {
    "test_alias":{
      "is_write_index": true 
    }
  }
}
```

This will add the date on the new roll over index name automatically. For example.

```
kbtest-ai-detector-2022.02.10-000001
kbtest-ai-detector-2022.02.11-000002
kbtest-ai-detector-2022.02.12-000003
kbtest-ai-detector-2022.02.13-000004
```